# 100% height body, absolute child to also take 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an absolute positioned element to take 100% height of `body`, where `body` is set to take 100% of content, that might exceed `window` height. But, I cannot seem to nail it.

CSS:

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    min-height: 100%;
}

#push
{
    padding-top: <to exceed window height>;
}

#absolute
{
    position: absolute;

    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;

    width: 100%; /* to take full width of body */

    height: 100%; /* to take full height of body */
}
```

HTML (assuming that this is all the content within `<body>`):

```
<div id="push"></div>
<div id="absolution"></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/DbV4R/

I have tried to make `#absolute` first child of body, last child (assuming that DOM hasn't yet calculated height at the start of body). Also, tried removing it's `height` property in exchange of `top: 0; bottom: 0;` - no luck.

Well, I assume it's because of `absolute` takes element out of *document's flow*, but, isn't there a way around it?

My actual example is where I want to have an absolute positioned background attachment element that holds numerous absolutely positioned elements. The element is going to have `overflow: hidden` to not make any scrollbars.

What options do I have here, except javascript and defined height?

#### Update:

If you inspect fiddle, you'll notice that `#absolution` takes 536px in height, where body takes 600.

I want, `#absolution`, to also take 600px - full height of `body`.

Comment: I didn't understood what you are really trying to do here

Comment: Updated with attempt to clarify the question.

Comment: Make the body position relative? http://jsfiddle.net/DbV4R/5/ remove native margin/padding for body to get rid of all the red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the body position relative? Remove native margin/padding for body to get rid of all the red (http://jsfiddle.net/DbV4R/6/)

http://jsfiddle.net/DbV4R/5

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I didn't got how our fiddles mixed up... would delete my answer anyways.. :)

Comment: Somehow didn't click to my head, that `body` should also be positioned relatively, geez. Thanks.